# What is the [physical] tag for?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

The [physical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/physical) tag currently has no summary, [wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/physical/info) or [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/physical/synonyms), but it is used on <s>93</s> 1 question<s>s</s>. Its purpose seems to be a bit vague, and usage is rather broad as a consequence — here are a few examples:

- [Physical memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29178416/4200092) i.e. RAM.
- [Physical devices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29090908/4200092) such as Android phones.
- [Physical measurements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28913677/4200092) i.e. millimeters, centimeters, and things like that.
- [Physical modeling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29303677/4200092) (I think?)
- [Physical... stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26084038/4200092) in general.
- [Whatever this means](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29413127/4200092).

**What should we do with this tag?**
☐ Disambiguate?
☐ Burninate?
☐ Other?

Note: We also have a [physical-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/physical-design) tag, which I initially assumed was for questions about the design of [IRL stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ergonomics/info), but which is *actually* used for database questions (well, [mainly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6144765/4200092)).

Comment: Documentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWz9VN40nCA

Comment: The one remaining question with the [tag:physical] tag was migrated to Unix & Linux (where the tag was removed).  Can a suitably privileged person (a moderator, or does it have to be a team member?) remove the [tag:physical] tag from the remnants of the question so that the tag dies a natural death.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33896/is-it-possible-to-retag-migrated-questions says it must be a moderator, I've already created a custom flag on this question detailing the request to remove that final question's tag

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Physical memory questions should be put under [memory-address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-address) tag, or one of the many other memory related tags as appropriate.

Questions about physical devices should probably go to [hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hardware),[android-hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-hardware), or some of the other hardware related tags.

Questions relating to the units used in physical measurements go under [units-of-measurement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/units-of-measurement) tag, which seems to exist for exactly this reason.

Physical modeling can probably be thrown under the [modeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modeling) tag, or perhaps the [simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simulation) tag

The rest of the stuff you mention is not significant enough to warrant its own tag in my opinion.

Given that nearly everything of value that is under this tag can fit in another tag, and that the tag's purpose is ambiguous, I say it should be burninated due to having no clear usage.

Comment: Consider modeling in terms of software architecture modelling, versus modeling in terms of computational modelling like fluid dynamics modeling, are certainly very different things.  I don't know if we have distinct tags for each.  Certainly removing "physical" is agreeable, although "physical data model" in context of database design is a phrase that has well established usage and meaning, but it is a very self contradicting phrase.

Comment: [modeling] is already taken to serve the computational simulation role, and so should not be used for this purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modeling

Comment: [data-modeling] would fill some retagging roles where appropriate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-modeling

Comment: @AaronLS [data-modeling] really doesn't seem to fit with the physical modeling that is being talked about. However, if [modeling] is alredy taken, then how about [simulation]? It specifically mentions physical systems in its description, and is fairly close to physical modeling in the sense that I think is being used here. Thoughts?

Comment: "[data-modeling] really doesn't seem to fit with the physical modeling" There are a tiny few questions tagged [physical] that ARE referring to data modelling, and so should be retagged [data-modeling]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27790240/84206

Comment: What I meant with [modeling] is taken, is that if the question refers to data modelling or software architecture modelling, then it should NOT be tagged [modeling] (since that wiki describes simulation), which I thought you were suggesting. But certainly I agree if it is computational modeling like fluid dynamics, then [modeling] is the appropriate tag. I see you edited to clarify.